# How to support aggregation and composition in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

**Aggregration**: The life time of the contained object is independent of the container object

**Composition**: The life time of the contained object is same as the container object.

In C++ , it is possible to do by the new and delete operators. Since C# doesn't provide the delete operator, how can we achieve aggregration and composition in C#?

Comment: "Aggregation" in the way you describe it isn't really a useful C++ concept. In C++, you generally always want to have definite responsibility.

Comment: Start by telling us why you care what the lifetime of an object is. The whole point of automatic memory management is to free you from the burden of having to care about niggling details like what the difference is between aggregation and composition. Explain why the difference is important and we can describe a mechanism that actually meets the specific need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lifetime follows from ownership, but ownership is the key idea in differentiating between aggregation and composition. In composition, the dependent object is wholly owned by the container.  The implication for this in C++ is that the container must take care to destroy it to avoid a memory leak.  In C# it depends on the kind of object/memory (managed or unmanaged) it is; the container must implement IDisposable and clean up unmanaged, compositional objects.  In both cases, aggregates exist independently of the container and are not the responsibility of the container to clean up after.

Answer (score 4):

[Disposal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If both objects implment IDisposable and Garbage collection then the parent objects Dispose method can call all childs objects dispose method in turn. This gives you composition.

You could then have methods on the parent object that dispose the child objects and not the parent i.e. aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `IDisposable` on your contained objects and call `Dispose` when you want them removed.